# NoSuchElementException even after check

Tags: java

```
for (final ArrayList<SmartPhone> smartPhones : smartPhonesCluster) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (SmartPhone smartPhone : smartPhones) {
                Queue<SmartPhoneTask> tasks = smartPhone.getSystem()
                                                        .getTaskQue();
                SmartPhoneTask task = null;
                assert tasks != null;
                try {
                    while (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
                        task = tasks.poll(); // This is the line throwing the exception (GlobalNetwork.java:118)
                        assert task != null;
                        task.execute();
                        task.onTaskComplete();
                    }
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

And log:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:788)
    at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:134)
    at java.util.LinkedList.poll(LinkedList.java:470)
    at com.wtsang02.reu.botnet.network.GlobalNetwork$1.run(GlobalNetwork.java:118)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "Thread-299" java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.wtsang02.reu.botnet.network.GlobalNetwork$1.run(GlobalNetwork.java:119)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

line 118 points to:

```
task=tasks.poll();
```

How to solve this? Queue is LinkedList implemenation if that makes a difference.

Comment: This method is declared synchronized. and Yes.

Comment: Is it possible for multiple `SmartPhone` instances to have the same queue? Or is each queue unique to a `SmartPhone` instance?

Comment: Each queue is created in constructor of each SmartPhone, each SmartPhone is unique.

Comment: The only other method that I know of is pushing to Queue, but ill make sure on that.

Comment: But are `SmartPhone`s shared across threads?

Comment: @yshavit It looks like from the code that each SmartPhone gets its own thread.

Comment: Since the polling is done in a different thread from pushing, make sure that the queue is thread safe (such as ConcurrentLinkedQueue). Otherwise code may be reordered so that the queue looks like non-empty for the polling thread before anything can be popped from it

Comment: `smartPhonesCluster` is a collection of lists of `SmartPhone`s. Is it possible that the same `SmartPhone` belongs to multiple lists in your cluster? If so, then you'd have multiple threads trying to poll the same queue. Double check that all of your lists of `SmartPhone` are disjoint.

Comment: No, cluster is just a list of list of smartphones. All smartphones are unique. I might just go thorugh line by line and see where the problem is. Since it looks like now, the problem isn't in the given code, and I would need to post too much, hence should be closed as too localized.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`LinkedList` is not thread-safe, so you need external synchronization if you access a `Linkedlist` on more than one thread. This synchronization is on some object (a `synchronized` method is just shorthand for "synchronize on `this`"), and both the gets and the puts must be synchronized on the *same* object. You're definitely doing that here, since you create a new thread for each `SmartPhone`, and then access that phone's `LinkedList` from there.

If one thread puts into the list while synchronized on `someObject1`, and then another thread reads that list while synchronized on `someObject2`, then this does *not* count as external synchronization -- the code is still broken.

Even if you used a thread-safe collection, it'd be possible to hit this exception if multiple threads are emptying the queue at the same time. For instance, imagine this:

```
thread A: put e into queue1
thread B: queue1.isEmpty()? No, so go on
thread C: queue1.isEmpty()? No, so go on
thread B: queue1.poll() // works
thread C: queue1.poll() // NoSuchElementException
```

You should use `BlockingQueue`, whose `poll()` method will return `null` if there are no more elements in the list. Keep pulling until you get a `null`, and then break the loop.

Comment: Its in the comments, but I should add to question. But the method is declared synchronized.

Comment: Unless I'm reading the code incorrectly, each `LinkedList` is only being accessed by one thread, since the `LinkedList` is supposed to be unique to its own `SmartPhone`, and there's one unique `SmartPhone` per thread.

Comment: @wtsang02 It doesn't matter if the method is, because from within that method you're starting a new thread, and that thread's `run` method is not synchronized. And even if it were, it wouldn't be synchronized with respect to whatever's putting things into the element. Remember that synchronization is always done on some monitor, and both the puts and the gets (including `isEmpty`) need to be synchronized on the _same_ monitor.

Comment: @DennisMeng There's definitely not one `SmartPhone` per thread, since just in this code fragment we see two threads with access to the same `List<SmartPhone>`.

Comment: I see. BlockingQue seems to be a better solution. Ill try that now.

Comment: I guess I'm misreading something then.

But yes, BlockingQueue would be better.

Comment: @DennisMeng Whatever thread the `for` loop is running on has access to a `List<SmartPhone> smartPhones`. Call this thread `A`. It then starts a new thread, call it thread `B`, that also has access to `smartPhones`. So, any `SmartPhone` in that list is known to both threads. There is a happens-before edge established at `start()`, but if any `SmartPhone`'s queue is modified in `A` (or some other thread `C`) after `B` has started, then it's not threadsafe.

Comment: Sorry I am still not understand on the statement "Even if you used a thread-safe collection, it'd be possible to hit this exception if multiple threads are emptying the queue at the same time.". Let say if I change it to use List Object instead of LinkList, will it still have possible to hit this error?